# How to create an If statement to check in an array for certain objects. Flash CS5 ActionScript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I am currently working on digitizing a card game a friend and myself designed, however I am having trouble with some of the coding in regards to the basics of it. What I have so far is the code will populate a "deck" (array) then randomize it then deal 4 four cards into a "hand" (array) it then currently loads movieclips of the 4 array entries onto the stage at certain co-ordinates.

What I want to do instead since I will quickly run out of room on stage is have set defined locations for each card type (currently they just load in what ever order they were drawn)

What I'm struggling with is getting the code to 1) perform a check if the array contains at least one of any card then load said card on the stage in it's co-ordinates then populate a dynamic text box to show how many of that card are in the hand.

So I'm pretty confident with most of the simpler functions but not creating an If statement to check for certain cards (objects) in an array, and also how to count how many duplicate objects of a certain type are in the same array.

Here is what I have currently, thanks in advance.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
stop();
//Create starting deck for player 1
var deck1 : Array = new Array(new attack(),new attack(),new attack(),new attack(),new attack(),new attack(),new ashe1(),new ashe1(),new flashss(),new ignitess());

//Create empty hand for player 1 and set up display variables
var hand1 : Array = [];
var attack1
var sa1
var sa2
var sa3
var sau
var ss1
var ss2

//Check player 1's deck
trace(deck1);

//Shuffle player 1's deck
function randomize1 (a : *, b : * ) : int {
    return ( Math.random() >.5 ) ? 1 : -1;
}
trace(deck1.sort( randomize1 ) );

//Draw first four cards for player 1
var drawcard1:MovieClip = deck1.shift();
trace(deck1);
trace(drawcard1);
hand1.push(drawcard1);
trace(hand1);
drawcard1 = deck1.shift();
trace(deck1);
trace(drawcard1);
hand1.push(drawcard1);
trace(hand1);
drawcard1 = deck1.shift();
trace(deck1);
trace(drawcard1);
hand1.push(drawcard1);
trace(hand1);
drawcard1 = deck1.shift();
trace(deck1);
trace(drawcard1);
hand1.push(drawcard1);
trace(hand1);

//Show player 1's hand on screen
addChild(hand1[0]);
hand1[0].x = 0.00;
hand1[0].y = 600.00;
addChild(hand1[1]);
hand1[1].x = 186.85;
hand1[1].y = 600.00;
addChild(hand1[2]);
hand1[2].x = 373.70;
hand1[2].y = 600.00;
addChild(hand1[3]);
hand1[3].x = 560.55;
hand1[3].y = 600.00;

//Show remaining card count left in deck on screen
var deck1l = deck1.length ;
player1count.text = deck1l
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you know how to iterate through an array with a for loop?

Comment: I have no idea what you just said to be honest. What I want is a if statement or similar that says if there is an Attck Object or one of the other objects in the array then addchild of that object. I just don't understand how to code that.

I was also after a way of counting duplicate objects in an array.

Comment: Both your deck and your hand are each an Array. If you are not sure what an Array or a for loop is, it'd be best if you take a step back to learn about how to iterate through an Array. If you do so, you'll be able to utilize that knowledge to iterate through an array and count the instances of a given card in either a deck or a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class cor the cards, then make subclasses for each type of card.

ie, you'll have class `Card` which will hold all the common properties of the cards. Then you might have `CombatCard`, `ActionCard`, `PassiveCard`, etc.

When drafting, you could use a simple and effective method to position them in the stage. Something like this:

Each card will have a public property type, which will be an int. ie, CombatCard's type will be 2.

Then you will have a vector of Points with the positions for each type of card, where each position corresponds to each card type. So the third element in the vector would have the coordinates to place combat cards.

When drafting, you would simply call a `positionCard(card)` which will read its type and add it to the point where it belongs.